# Supset proof of invertible functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm struggling with the following question:

$M$ is a non-empty set, $G$ is the set of invertible functions $f: M \rightarrow M$. Let $x \in M$ and $G'=\lbrace f \in G: f(x)=x \rbrace$.

Now I have to proove that $G'$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I can use the following lemma:

Let $M$ be a group and $M \supseteq M'$. If

- $\forall a,b \in M'$ also $a \circ b \in M'$
- $e \in M$
- $a^{-1} \in M'$

then $M'$ is supgroup of $M$.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: @ulead86 $G'$ isn't properly defined, there's no quantification in the condition $f(x)=x$.

Comment: THis question is ill-posed: "set of invertible functions"...from $\,M\,$ to itself, I presume...? What is $\,x\,$ in the definition of $\,G'\,$ ? One single, fixed element in $\,M\,$ ? What is a "supset of $\,G\,$ ? A set containing $\,G\,$ ?...

Comment: For that matter, what are you doing with your $a\in M$? It isn't mentioned anywhere else in the question you've posed. Should it be?

Comment: sorry for my mistakes, I changed the question

Comment: Perhaps you mean "subset" = subset = "Teilmenge"...? But then, you say $\,M'\subset M\,$ and *after this* you ask to show "then $\,M'\,$ is subset of $\,M\,$ ..." ? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah ofc, I meant supgroup. Sorry for the confusion :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $G$ is intended to be the **group** of invertible functions $M\to M$ under composition, that you mean $$G'=\{f\in G:f(a)=a\}$$ (where $a$ is some fixed element of $M$), and that you wish to show that $G'$ is a **subgroup** of $G$.

To show closure under composition, you'll need to show that if $f,g:M\to M$ are invertible functions such that $f(a),g(a)=a,$ then $f\circ g:M\to M$ is invertible (one-to-one and onto) and $f\circ g(a)=a$.

Consider the function $M\to M$ given by $x\mapsto x$ for all $x\in M$. Is this invertible? Does it take $a\mapsto a$? How does it behave under composition with other functions $M\to M$?

To show inverses, take $f:M\to M$ invertible with $f(a)=a$. Show that $f^{-1}:M\to M$ is also invertible and that $f^{-1}(a)=a.$

Comment: The element $\,a\,$ *still* is unquantified in your definition of $\,G'\,$ ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Apparently the OP changed $a$ to $x$ without my noticing. I will adjust.

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry again for the troubles :(